# What does ‘Response Cache Headers’ and ‘Cache Time (seconds)’ in Geoserver really do?

Tags: geoserver, http-headers

I am trying to understand what these two settings do and how they can be used to influence how the user’s browser caches a tile.

From the Geoserver documentation:

> “HTTP Settings—Cache parameters that apply to the HTTP response from client requests. If Response Cache Headers is selected, GeoServer will not request the same tile twice within the time specified in Cache Time. One hour measured in seconds (3600), is the default value for Cache Time.”

From this I infer that either ‘Expires’ or ‘Cache-Control’ HTTP headers will be added to the response and, if Cache-Control is added, then the value that goes into ‘max-age’ will be ‘Cache Time’. Is this what is meant to happen?

However when I turn on ‘Response Cache Headers’ and look at the HTTP response header on the client I see no difference from the case when the ‘Response Cache Headers’ is not on.

Comment: are you sure you are hitting the cache? can you add the url you are trying